# Iterate through other table in a Case when clause

Tags: sql, for-loop, foreach, case-when

I have the following CASE WHEN clause

```
SELECT T0.foo, CASE WHEN T0.Column1 = 'Y' THEN '8mm' 
            WHEN T0.Column2 = 'Y' THEN '10mm' 
            WHEN T0.Column7 = 'Y' THEN '13mm'
            WHEN T0.Column50 = 'Y' THEN '30mm' END AS 'Width'
            ...
FROM Table1 T0
```

Actually the mapping is the result of another query `Table2`

```
=========================
   Column1      Column2
=========================
   Column1      8mm
   Column2      10mm
   Column7      13mm
   Column50     30mm 
   ...          ...
```

I am looking for a way to generate the CASE WHEN Clause in the first statement with some sort of for each loop or iteration through the result of the second statement.

Pseudo Code:

```
SELECT T0.foo, CASE WHEN (Select Column1 FROM Table2) = 'Y' THEN (SELECT Column2 FROM Table2) as 'Width'
FROM Table1 T0
```

Comment: Sounds like a real bad data design to me... Anyway, you could use dynamic SQL to build a query in the style of your first query from the data of `table2` but you cannot do such a thing as in your pseudo code.

Comment: Thank you. I totaly agree on the bad data design I would have done it differently but so far changing it would be much more work at this point (human factor). Could you elaborate on your suggestion? I know my pseudo code does not work at all. I would be happy with anything similar, that does the job.

Comment: You can iterate over the rows of `table2` and build strings like `'WHEN T0.' || table2.column1 || ' = ''Y'' THEN ''' || table2.column2 || ''''` (`||` is the concatenation operator, it might be different in your DBMS but is almost certainly provides a means of string concatenation). Concatenate them together and prepend/append the rest (`'SELECT ...'` and `'... FROM ...'`) and you have generated the query text. Store it in a variable, say `query`. Then execute this query text. How to do the latter may again vary from DBMS to DBMS. It may look similar to `EXECUTE query;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `join`:

```
SELECT T1.foo, t2.Width
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON (t1.column1 = 'Y' AND t2.column = 'Column1') OR
        (t1.column1 = 'Y' AND t2.column = 'Column7') OR
        . . .
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. As I said Table2 is the result of a query, as I want to avoid "hard coding" the column names and descriptions (e.g. 8mm). The results can vary over time, thus the statement should be dynamic. As far as I understood your suggestions that would mean "hard coding" again.

Comment: @FelixHaupts . . . Fix your data structure.  Don't store `table1` in this format.  You probably want a junction table, with one row per "foo" and one per object.

Comment: As stated above, changing the Data Structure seems harder than finding a solution for the issue above. Whe are talking about an implementation with many users and other queries that are allready using this "bad structure". I might simply revert to hard coding and then adding new values when necessary... :-( thanks anyways